# Collocations of "Uncertainty"

Tags: collocation, statistics

I'm trying to find the right preposition to go after "uncertainty", as in statistical uncertainties.

I'm guessing that it might be "the uncertainty on the prognosis", but I'm not sure.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: "uncertainty *of* the prognosis", perhaps.

Comment: *Of* is the preposition generally used with *certain*. *To be certain of*.  I'd use *uncertainty of the prognosis* :https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uncertainty+of%2Cuncertainty+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuncertainty%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuncertainty%20on%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Statistical uncertainties are calculated using formulas and so I'm not sure if they go with the same collocations as subjective uncertainties.

Comment: Statistical uncertainty of/on: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=statistical+uncertainty+of%2C+statistical+uncertainty+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstatistical%20uncertainty%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstatistical%20uncertainty%20on%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Looks like both are in use, although the use of "of" is decreasing and the use of "on" is increasing. Thanks for pointing me to that tool.

Comment: Or you could dump the preposition and use "uncertainty regarding the prognosis"—in U.S. English, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are such collocations specifically related to "uncertainty":

*uncertainty **about***

*uncertainty **as to***

as described in this specialized reference book:

**The BBI Combinatory Dictionary of English: Your guide to collocations and grammar**. Paperback – March 19, 2010
by Morton Benson, Evelyn Benson

which you should make part of your library.

Comment: In terms of statistics, there's also "uncertainty on" (see above comments for reference), but thanks for the reference to the book. It looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use "uncertainty of" when describing a *method*, but "uncertainty on" when describing a *result* derived from that method.

Hard to explain why, but I feel like the imperfection is really an intrinsic property ("belongs to") the method, while it is something imposed upon the final number.

I also think that e.g. "The uncertainty of fraction *x*" is a bit awkward because a mathematical fraction has no intrinsic concept of uncertainty -- that is an external concept, arguably highlighting that we are using a shorthand for "The uncertainty of our estimate for fraction *x*"... but such pedantic expansions do nothing for readability.

Answer (score 0):

"uncertainly of" is not bad but you may find that expanding the sentence helps. As in "The degree of uncertainty contained in the process..." or "The output of the process has a high degree of uncertainty which we can quantify using..."